# How to show a JavaScript popup when an exception occurs in a WebMethod

Tags: javascript, vb.net, exception

I want to let the user know if there is an error when a query is processed. The error should be shown in a popup using javascript.

With my code, the `Throw new exception` does work. The message is not shown.

Can anybody help me please?

My html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"><br />
    Function gotoSave() {
        PageMethods.saveMaster(deData, tipe, OnRequestComplete, OnRequestError);
    } 

    Function OnRequestComplete(result, userContext, methodName) {
        if (result != '') { 
            alert(result); 
        }
    }

    Function OnRequestError(error, userContext, methodName) {
        if (error != null) { 
            alert(error.get_message()); 
        }
    }
</script>
```

My code behind (VB):

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Sub saveMaster(ByVal deData As String, ByVal tipe As String)
  ..
  ..
  Try
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  Catch ex As Exception
      Throw New Exception("Fout: Data not saved" & vbCrLf & ex.Message.ToString)
  End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Please indent your code with four spaces instead of using HTML.  http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0):

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("ClientScript", String.Format("<script>alert('Fout: Data not saved {0}{1}');</script>", vbCrlf, ex.Message))
```

The above method should do the trick, but it is a bit old.  There are other ways to do this, you may want to Google RegisterStartupScript and read about it.  Just make sure you comment out the Throw when you put this in place.